# match and replace string items in list with string items from another list

Tags: python, list, string-matching

I have three lists - `base, match, and replac` ; `match` and `replac` are same length

```
base = ['abc', 'def', 'hjk']

match = ['abc', 'hjk']

replac = ['abcde', 'hjklm']
```

I would like to modify the `base` list by matching string items in `match` and replace these with the same index item from `replac`.

Expected output: `base = ['abcde', 'def', 'hjklm']`

Comment: The best way that I can think of is to make a dict with words in `match` as keys and words in `replac` as values, then loop through words in `base` and replace them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I'd do it:

```
mapp = dict(zip(match,replac))
res = [mapp[e] if e in mapp else e for e in base]
```